# Calculate Out data Kb/s for specific PID

Tags: bash

I have this command

```
cat /proc/8221/net/netstat | grep 'IpExt: ' | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $9 }'
```

This shows me out bytes in that moment right?

If yes, how can i show total kb/s in just one command for specific pid?
I need to do a simple sleep(1) and a subtraction right and then conver the bytes into kilobytes...

How i can do that in one command??

And also another one question.
If i have 2 PIDs to check for total byte sent, how again i can do that in one command so i dont have to wait for 2 seconds ? In a few words, how i can check multiple pids, but having only 1 sleep(1) command?

Thanks

Comment: a quick search using google found [this](http://www.slashroot.in/find-network-traffic-and-bandwidth-usage-process-linux). it might be helpful

Comment: i want it manually, not with the use of a software

Comment: either way it is going to be some utility that most likely wont come by default in any OS. natively maybe `ipfw` or `iptables` with some trickery. PID and processes are not quantities that netstat will filter by nor any other common program. Wireshark now comes to mind as it's filtering is powerful. imo will have to install something at the end